# Menu eats space in mobile view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use `Bootsstrap v3.1.1` for building responsive UI. It works okay, except menu "eats" some space in mobile view. It can be seen from the following images.
**At wide display:**
[image]

**and mobile view:**
[image]>

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                   data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>                
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                    
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu1", "Menu1", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu2", "Menu1", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu3", "Menu1", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu4", "Menu1", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu5", "Menu1", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu6", "Menu1", "Home")</li>    

                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">        
        <p>1. This text can be seen on personal computer, but not in mobile</p>
        <p>2. This text can be seen on personal computer, but not in mobile</p>
        <p>3. This text can be seen on personal computer, but not in mobile</p>

        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <footer style="display: table; text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">

        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Fix**

Try this

Check Demo **[here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZpNpWJ?editors=1010)**

> Remember: margin-top value will be more than the height of navbar

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
     .body-content {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It becomes very far from the top at PC view

Comment: @StepUp Use `media-query`

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding CSS to it as your text is hidden under the menu

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.body-content{
margin-top:5px;
}
}
```

Comment: it does not work. The row cannot be seen in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using paragraph tags perhaps try using row and col-md-12 as is common in BS.

```
<row>
  <div class='col-md-12'> this text is visible</div>
</row>
<row>
  <div class='col-md-12'> this text is visible</div>
</row>
<row>
  <div class='col-md-12'> this text is visible</div>
</row>
```

Comment: it does not work. The row cannot be seen in mobile view.

Comment: use class mt-50 as well, to give it margin. See also @Med answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar is fixed on the top and your .navbar class have `min-height: 50px;` so add a new div like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <div id="main">
   <div class="container">
   <p> your content here </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#main { 
 padding-top: 70px; 
}
```

If you want to display elements only in (medium/large devices) use this code:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  p { display: none }
}
```